# How can i get data from flash in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3

I was wondering that how can i get data 
from flash file in my ASP.NET application?

Comment: What sort of data you want to extract from Flash ?

Comment: You could have elaborate a little more, anyway here something that might help: http://www.keylimetie.com/Blog/2007/12/18/How-to-Communicate-between-ASPNET-and-Flash/

Comment: I want creat a flash game web site...I want when a user play a game and get score in his game after end game i save his score in data base like this https://www.lumosity.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET to Flash: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/

Flash to ASP.NET: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1223108&page=1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an open source library called [FluorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) for this.
It is basically a flash remoting gateway, which mimics the functionality of BlazeDS.

I also found a basic [tutorial](http://www.thesilentgroup.com/fluorine/fluorine/page.html) for this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is most of the time the other way around:

Flash application contacts the back-end, and sends data, processes reply ..

In its simplest form, you POST/GET an dosomething.aspx with a couple of URL parameters and let it update your storage.